# Odds of ellipse from five random points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections

It's known that [five points determine a conic section](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FivePointsDetermineAConicSection/).  Five random points can go right into the $6\times6$ matrix, and then the $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2$ part can be looked at.  If $B^2-4AC<0$, it's an ellipse.  Five random points will almost never produce circles or parabolas, so the results will be ellipses and hyperbolas.  What are the odds of an ellipse?

In a random run of 100000 trials, I got 27974 ellipses. "It's less than $e/10$," seems like a solid answer.  Anyone have anything more specific?

EDIT:  As Oscar points out, I should have said "It's more than $e/10$."  In my trial, real-values points were randomly picked from a unit square.  [Square Triangle Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTrianglePicking.html) methods might be applicable.

EDIT2: Aretino points out that [odds of a convex pentagon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html) are $49/144≈0.34$. So how can points making a convex pentagon give a non-ellipse?  Here's a picture. With the red points fixed, the black points are outside of the convex hull yet still yield a non-ellipse.

[image: non-ellipses]

EDIT3: That spray of points above goes back to Newton, Philosophiae naturalis
principia mathematica, 1687, where he solved the [4 point parabola](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/mwoltermann/Dorrie/45.pdf) ([another version](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath037/kmath037.htm)). If a point is between one of the two parabolas and the degenerate lines, then it gives a hyperbola.

Comment: Uh ... $27974/100000>e/10$.  $e=2.71828...$.

Comment: Good eye, Oscar.  I'm just being stupid.

Comment: What do you mean by random points?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the domain from which you pick the points does not make a difference? Ellipseness is affine-invariant, so at least we know that points picked uniformly from any *parallelogram* will have the same probability, but I'm not confident about saying the same for points picked from, say, a triangle, or from a normal distribution.

Comment: Rahul -- Very likely.  I link to Square Triangle Picking. Compare that to Circle Triangle picking. If one point is in the convex hull of the others, it won't be an ellipse.

Comment: I think the probability of getting an ellipse is very close (if not the same) as the probability that the five points are the vertices of a convex polygon.

Comment: [I found at this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html) that the probability that five points chosen at random inside a square are the vertices of a convex pentagon is $49/144\approx0.34$. Not far from the results you got, but definitely not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ be the probability of getting an ellipse. For the five points to form a convex polygon, they must either lie on an ellipse (with probability $x$) or lie on the same branch of a hyperbola: if each point has probability $1/2$ of lying on either branch of the hyperbola  this should happen with probability ${1\over16}(1-x)$.

As the [probability that five points chosen at random inside a square are the vertices of a convex pentagon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SylvestersFour-PointProblem.html) is $49/144$, we have the equation
$$
x+{1\over16}(1-x)={49\over144},
\quad\hbox{whence:}\quad
x={8\over27}\approx0.296.
$$
This result is however a little higher than simulations suggest.

Comment: I think that's about 99% of it. Where does the (1-x)/16 come from?  Your odds of 8/27 or about .2963 seem high compared to random runs which tend to .279.  But you definitely have a large part of the answer.

Comment: I supposed that each point has probability $0.5$ of lying on either branch of the hyperbola. But that might not be exactly true.

Comment: If this is correct, it implies that the probability would change if you picked your points inside a domain of a different shape (picking five points in the unit circle, for example), since the result of Sylvester's problem depends on the shape of the domain.

Comment: I've just run a simulation taking a triangular domain: the probability turns out to be around $0.22$, while the same reasoning as above gives in this case ${7\over27}\approx0.26$.

Comment: I must correct the simulation result in my previous comment: the result for a triangle is about $0.24$. I was using by mistake a non-uniform distribution.